# Magento 2 how to move default.html from base folder to custom theme folder

Tags: magento2

I have created Magento_Catalog folder in custom theme and moved template files there which are working fine. Now i want to move the files from module-catalog base folder to custom theme Magento_Catalog folder.

Want to move **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount** folder.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base folder contain file which is used by both front and admin

You can copy:

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

To below folder:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

For testing you can add a class with `price-container span` and see changes on front end.

Hope above will help!

Comment: thanks, its working

Comment: welcome :) glad to know.